# Given $\phi(t)$, understanding/visualizing what $\phi'(t)$ is

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I'm trying to understand a basic argument in linear algebra, and getting confused.

Let $\phi:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Denote $\phi(t)=(x(t), y(t))$. In the expression 'the tangent to the curve is $d\phi(t)/dt = (x'(t),y'(t))$', I'm having a difficult time comprehending this. I know that this is the definition of a tangent, but how should I visualize that? Should I draw the curve $\phi(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then draw the tangent line to the curve at $t=t_0$, and is that related, somehow, with the 'tangent' $\phi'(t_0)$? It doesn't seem likely that the vector $(x'(t_0),y'(t_0))$ represents the tangent line that I drew.

Based on [Difference between a point of a curve $\gamma(t_0)$ and the vector $\gamma'(t_0)$ tangent to $\gamma$ in $t_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625563/difference-between-a-point-of-a-curve-gammat-0-and-the-vector-gammat-0?rq=1) and [Help understanding the definition of tangent vector or tangent plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/help-understanding-the-definition-of-tangent-vector-or-tangent-plane?rq=1), I've concluded that $\phi'(t)$ expresses the 'direction' of the tangent line at time $t$. That is, the tangent line is just calculating the vector $\phi'(t)$, and then extending the vector of finite length into a line. Is this correct? How can I prove this formally?

Comment: I do not see why you need (x, y). You have a function of which is a curve. The differential describes the slope of the tangent.